# NivoSlider first image is not displayed

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, nivo-slider

I have a slider on a wordpress website and I have a problem with first image. Is not displayed. After all loads, this works too. 
Here is the link for the slider: http://www.teenbetween.relationshipsireland.com/

Comment: Tested under chrome (windows 7), seems to work fine

Comment: First time, 1st image isn't there

Comment: I had the same problem.
Try add `z-index:1` to `.nivo-main-image`